Bound an integral from below
the following question appeared in my calc exam:
prove that there exists some $c>0$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N$,
$$cn \le\int_0^n f(x)dx$$
whereas $f(x) = x^2 - \lfloor x^2 \rfloor$
I've tried evaluating it directly, by
$$\int_0^n f(x)dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-1} \int_{\sqrt(k)}^{\sqrt(k+1)} x^2-k = \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-1} \int_{\sqrt(k)}^{\sqrt(k+1)} x^2 - \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-1} \int_{\sqrt(k)}^{\sqrt(k+1)} k = \int_0^n x^2dx - \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-1} k\cdot(\sqrt{k+1} -\sqrt k) \ge \frac{n^3}{3}-\sum_{k=0}^{n^2-1} \frac{k}{2\sqrt k} = \frac{n^3}{3}- \frac{1}{2}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-1}\sqrt k $$
which seems promising but I couldn't get any further. I believe there is some integral theorem to be applied rather then the calculation I did. would really appreciate a hint/direction

The final sum is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^{n^2}\sqrt{x}~dx = \frac{2n^3}{3}$ so perhaps some sort of error term would be the only thing remaining. Not sure if there is an easier way from the start though

Have you tried integration by parts with the Riemann-Stieltjes integral? (It is far from clear what "calc" courses entail in your country.)

the question should be solvable with basic propeties of Riemann integral (riemann sums, mid value theoream, fundemental theoream of calculs etc)

By substitution $x=\sqrt{t}$ the integral is transformed to $$\int\limits_0^{n^2}{1\over 2\sqrt{t}}(t-\lfloor t\rfloor) \,dt= \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\int\limits_{k-1}^{k}{1\over 2\sqrt{t}}(t-\lfloor t\rfloor) \,dt \\ \ge {1\over 2}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}{1\over \sqrt{k}}\int\limits_{k-1}^{k}(t-\lfloor t\rfloor) \,dt\\  ={1\over 4}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}{1\over\sqrt{k}}\ge {1\over 4}n^2{1\over \sqrt{n^2}}= {1\over 4}n$$ On the way we have used the fact that the function $t-\lfloor t\rfloor$ is periodic with period $1.$ Hence $$\int\limits_{k-1}^{k}(t-\lfloor t\rfloor) \,dt= \int\limits_{0}^{1}(t-\lfloor t\rfloor) \,dt={1\over 2}$$
